# Qt check box check all button

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox

I have a work project that I am working on. We are using Qt to design a program and on one of our pages we have check boxes for different display options. As there are over six options and often as not we either need all on or all off I need to find a way to make a check all or check none button. I am very new to qt and Slots and signals. I cannot share our code as it is proprietary. Long story short I am lost in the UI. Am I just missing something simple in the Design page or do I need to be in the CPP file editing it manually? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish most of this by connecting the `toggled(bool)` signal of the "check all" box to the `setChecked(bool)` slot of the individual check boxes.

But you probably also want to change the state of the "check all" box based on the state of the individual check boxes. For example, if the user manually unchecks each individual box, you may want the "check all" box unchecked as well. To do this, you could just connect the `toggled(bool)` signal for each check box to a user-defined slot which will check the state of each box and take the appropriate action.